# Adding the tag value of type refGuid

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

We have created the elements using C#. Now We have the created the tag of type RefGuid.So how can we add the value to that tag such that it should refer to the particular element.When We open the diagram in EA when I check the tag in properties it should show which element the tag is referencing.So how can the tag of type RefGuid can be set through addin.
Before setting the value for tag how can we check whether the tag is of Type=RefGuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the GUID (including the curly braces) to the value of the tag. E.g.

```
tag.value = '{CDE8A0BB-512C-4709-9A87-B34C8DD5E2FF}';
tag.Update();
```

Comment: How can we check the tag is of type refguid

Comment: I guess you can't since it's in the MDG which is not accessible.